# lxml html ubnable to parse display block

Tags: python, parsing, lxml

I'm trying to scrape this website - [of dutyfree product](https://bhx.worlddutyfree.com/bhx_en/catalogsearch/result/?q=chocolate)
and get a list of choclate products, but actually i'm only getting nothing..

- my code:

```
from lxml import html
import lxml.html
import requests
import lxml

tree = html.fromstring(url.content)
    data_price = tree.xpath('//div[@class="main"]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]')
    for item in data_price:
        print(lxml.html.tostring(item))
```

- f12 telling something about blocing the display

[image: here is the F12 description]

Comment: It seems that the page forbid spider to scrapy it.

Comment: how can i avoid the forbidding?

Comment: An easy way is using ``selenium``.

Comment: and what if I can't use selenium? :/

Comment: Maybe use a proper request headers.

Comment: can you give an concretic example?

Comment: For,example:add ``user-agent`` to your headers,or ``cookie``.

Comment: I will try and keep you posted! thank you

Comment: this site is keeping the cookcies valid only one day so for now this option is not an option anymore, any other options?

Comment: `display: block` does not mean that the display is blocked. (It obviously isn't; it displays just fine.) See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: thank you rici, do you know any other options to avoid the forbidding of scrapping websites?

Comment: @rici HAHAHA,``block`` is a display way in css.I mean that you can not get the full page source code only by ``requests.get(url)``

Comment: Actually,if it hard to get the full page source.Just learn something about ``selenium``,it is easy.

Comment: I know selenium, but it's not fit to the current situation. I want to analyze data and show it on local host, selenium will not help me so much here because I need the computre accessible

Comment: **Please provide a [mcve].**

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use Selenium. How does Selenium affect accessibility of your computer?

Comment: Also, and more importantly, I'm pretty sure your problem is the XPATH search. I think the data you're looking for is in div[2] but you're usually better off using class or id searches rather than counting children.